# How to sent data from streambuilders to multiprovider using Firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, provider

I tried to load data from firestore throught **StreamBuilders** and then, sent this data to **Multiprovider**.

In this view we can see:

1) First StreamBuilder to load Games.

2) Second StreamBuilder to load Teams

3) Data from StreamBuilders to Multiprovider

4) MaterialApp where we have one button and one txt on screen center. 
When we press the button, we call to 3 providers, and print some data from them all.

```
void main() {
  FlutterError.onError = (FlutterErrorDetails details) {
    FlutterError.dumpErrorToConsole(details);
    if (kReleaseMode)
      exit(1);
  };
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  get bottomNavBarIndex => null;
  var db = new FirebaseContext(); // My Firebase class  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<List<Game>>( // First StreamBuilder to load games
      stream: db.loadGames(),
      builder: (context, snapshot1) {
        return StreamBuilder<List<Team>>( // Second StreamBuilder to load teams
          stream: db.loadTeams(),
          builder: (context, snapshot2) {
            if(!snapshot1.hasData || !snapshot2.hasData){
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            }else if(snapshot1.hasError || snapshot2.hasError){
              return Center(child: Text('Error reading data!'));
            }else{
              return MultiProvider(
                providers: [
                  ChangeNotifierProvider<GameProvider>.value(value: GameProvider(snapshot1.data)),
                  ChangeNotifierProvider<TeamProvider>.value(value: TeamProvider(snapshot2.data)),
                  ChangeNotifierProvider<PlayerProvider>.value(value: PlayerProvider(snapshot1.data))
                ], 
                child: MaterialApp( // Empieza la App.
                  title: 'Welcome to Flutter',
                  home: Scaffold(
                    appBar: AppBar(
                      title: Text('Welcome to Flutter'),
                    ),
                    body: Center(
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                            color: Colors.blue[500],
                            onPressed: () 
                            {
                              // Get the value of each provider (List<Object>) and print the first item of them all
                              List<Game> games = Provider.of<GameProvider>(context).games;
                              List<Team> teams = Provider.of<TeamProvider>(context).teams;
                              List<Player> players = Provider.of<PlayerProvider>(context).players;
                              print('${games[0].id}');
                              print('${teams[0].id}');
                              print('${players[0].name} ${players[0].surname}');
                            }
                          ),
                          Text('Press me',
                          )
                        ]
                      )
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              );
            }
          }
       );
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Then, when I Press the button, it shows this message:

```
    The following ProviderNotFoundError was thrown while handling a gesture:
Error: Could not find the correct Provider<GameProvider> above this StreamBuilder<List<Team>> Widget

To fix, please:

  * Ensure the Provider<GameProvider> is an ancestor to this StreamBuilder<List<Team>> Widget
  * Provide types to Provider<GameProvider>
  * Provide types to Consumer<GameProvider>
  * Provide types to Provider.of<GameProvider>()
  * Always use package imports. Ex: `import 'package:my_app/my_code.dart';
  * Ensure the correct `context` is being used.

If none of these solutions work, please file a bug at:
https://github.com/rrousselGit/provider/issues
```

Comment: You can listen to Streams without using a `StreamProvider`. To give you an example I need to understand what your methods `db.loadGames()` and `db.loadTeams()` are doing. I assume they are outputting a stream, but is that what you want to receive?  It looks like you want to just fetch data from Firestore. In case you do what to use Streams then the implementation will be a bit more complex to have a Stream's snapshots triggering listening to another Stream.

Comment: db.loadGames() returns a Strem<List<Game>> and db.loadTeams() returns a Stream<List<Team>>

Comment: Do you intend to have the Teams Stream be listened to again every time a new snapshot of the Games Stream comes through?

Comment: Yes, I think with Consumer<X> may helps but I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that these codes

```
List<Game> games = Provider.of<GameProvider>(context).games;
List<Team> teams = Provider.of<TeamProvider>(context).teams;
........
```

are finding the Providers above your StreamBuilders. You can look at your errors.

So what you can do is declare the providers as variables outside your build method. Add a function in your providers that would allow you to set the data you need via functions instead of constructors,
then pass these variables inside your `MultiProvider`.

For example:

```
... outside build Method
_notificationProvider = NotificationProvider();

... in MultiProvider
ChangeNotifierProvider(
            create: (context) =>
                _notificationProvider..initializeNotificationListeners(data)
)
```

As you can see in the change notifier provider, we can set the provider we need, and at the same time call a function. You just have to use `..` after the assigning provider.

Then, in your `onPressed` function, you can directly access these providers via their variables, so that you won't have the problem where the providers are being searched above the StreamBuilders